# Add tweetNaCL-js crypto library to CouchDB validate_doc function

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, commonjs, nacl-cryptography

I am trying to validate a document using public key crypto ([tweetnacl](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/nacl.js)).
I know that [you can add commonjs modules](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/commonjs_modules_in_couchdb/) to validate functions but haven't been able to.

```
{
 "_id": "_design/validate_update",
 "language": "javascript",
 "validate_doc_update": 
           "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx){     
                verify=require('lib/validation').sign.detached.verify;
                if(verify(newDoc.message, new.Doc.signature, oldDoc.publicKey)){
                     return true;
                }
               }",
 "lib": {
     "validation": "exports.nacl=(function(nacl){..... })"
 }
}
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
  Module require('lib/validation') raised error (new TypeError("func.apply is not a function", "/usr/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js", 1181))
```

I suppose I  have to somehow change the tweetnacl code to be interpreted as a commonjs module?

Comment: did this get solved?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the initialisation of the NaCl lib as commonjs module is failing because its an anonymous function - try to give NaCl `exports` as context:

```
"lib": {
 "validation": "(function(nacl){..... })(exports)"
}
```